# Using two different clocks in my assertion

Tags: system-verilog

I am using SystemVerilog to write assertions in order to test the behavior of my design. In my design I have two clock : 
the usual `CLK_int` and another clock called `I2C_IF_SCL_out`.
In the specification of my design:

`SDA_Tick_shift`= 01 for one CLK_int period, 10 `CLK_int` periods after falling edge of `I2C_IF_SCL_out`.

What I am asking is can I use two clocks in my clocking block `@(posedge CLK_int)` and `@(I2C_IF_SCL_out)`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `CLK_int` has a much higher frequency than `I2C_IF_SCL_out`, what you probably want is

```
assert property (@posedge CLK_int $fell(I2C_IF_SCL_out) |-> ##10 SDA_Tick_shift==2'b01)
```

Otherwise, you would have to explain your requirements in much more detail.